# How to combine icu4x word segmenter with additional dictionary

Tags: rust, icu, text-segmentation

The icu4x [`icu_segmenter::WordSegmenter`](https://docs.rs/icu_segmenter/latest/icu_segmenter/struct.WordSegmenter.html) seems like the best word segmenter out there.

I don't understand how data providers work with word segmentation at all. It seems very complicated to me and I couldn't find any example.

I need it for Thai. I guess it uses the LSTM segmenter by default. It's better than anything I've seen before by default. It still has trouble with a lot of exotic names. Which is why I'd like to add my dictionary to it for personal use.

How to do that?